# C# Multiple Regex Replace

Tags: c#, regex

How can I manipulate this code to run multiple Regex.Replaces on the same string?

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string SkipImgTags(this string html, int length)
    {
        string strReplaceHtml = Regex.Replace(html, @"(< *?/*)strong( +?|>)", @"(< *?/*)bold( +?|>)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);


        return strReplaceHtml;
    }
}
```

I attempted to stack the following but was unsuccessful:

```
string strReplaceHtml = Regex.Replace(html, @"(< *?/*)strong( +?|>)", @"(< *?/*)bold( +?|>)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
string strReplaceHtml = Regex.Replace(html, @"(< *?/*)em( +?|>)", @"(< *?/*)italic( +?|>)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are close. Consider the following minor change to your code...

```
string strReplaceHtml = Regex.Replace(html, @"(< *?/*)strong( +?|>)", @"(< *?/*)bold( +?|>)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
strReplaceHtml = Regex.Replace(strReplaceHtml , @"(< *?/*)em( +?|>)", @"(< *?/*)italic( +?|>)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Good Luck!